# Will a divorce affect my co-signed vehicle?

Tags: united-states, auto-loan, co-sign, divorce, pennsylvania

Not sure if this question should be here or in the law exchange, but basically my dad cosigned my car loan for the purposes of rate reduction (as I had virtually no credit history at the time). My dad didn't put any money down, doesn't pay for any principal, and hasn't paid any of the loan's interest. I pay for everything. For all functional purposes, it is totally my vehicle and he only co-signed so I'd get a lower interest rate.
Fast forward a few years and my dad and stepmom are getting a divorce. I don't know the particulars of divorce settlements, but does the fact that he co-signed my auto loan mean that technically it's his asset and would be subject to any divorce agreement? If so, how can I amend this? I do not want to be involved in that process whatsoever, particularly financially.

Comment: who's on the title? Just you? Or you and your dad?

Comment: Please add country **and state** tags; it makes an important difference.

Comment: PA isn't a community property state.  Thus -- if anything -- your father *might* technically be able to saddle her with half of your debt, therefore keeping more for himself.  (Naturally, that would be fought over.)

Comment: @RonJohn can you elaborate a little? What is a community property state and how does that directly relate to my situation?

Comment: @mkennedy I believe it is just me but I am not sure. Will check and get back to you

Comment: Community Property is a notion in some states with French and Spanish heritage; all assets and liabilities acquired during the marriage are the property of the "community" (aka the marriage partners), to be split evenly upon divorce.  **Other states (like PA)** "equitably distribute" assets and liabilities, which means that your father's lawyer *might* be able to convince the judge that your stepmother deserves half of the debt.  (Naturally, your mother's lawyer would fight it.)

Comment: Since this is a Money question - Can you share some particulars about the loan? What was the loan amount, how much is left on the loan, what are the monthly payments, and how much can you afford to pay it off? That may help consider solutions like refinancing or just paying the loan off. If you have no loan, or a loan w/o a co-signer then the divorce question becomes moot.

Comment: "He doesn't pay any..." do you? When it comes to financial institutions, they're unlikely to even look at your file as long as you're making your scheduled payments. Even if a loan was issued in error, they're almost certainly going to just keep collecting your money and deal with whatever situation it is if you stop paying.

Comment: Is the vehicle title solely in your name?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The co-signer is responsible for paying the loan back if you can’t or don’t want to pay. Being co-signer doesn’t give them any rights to your car. What happens in the private life of the co-signer, like divorce, makes no difference, they are still co-signer.

In extreme situations, like your dad co-signed but it was actually your wealthy ex-mother in law who would have paid, well, that’s just too bad for your dad. Shouldn’t have co-signed.

Comment: While simply being a co-signer doesn't confer rights, if the OP were to default and the 'co' was required to make payments, would the 'co' then acquire a property interest in proportion to payments he makes?

Comment: @JimMack No. They aren't buying the car, they're paying back the loan.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so in other words: regardless of who's obligated to pay for the loan, whoever is on the vehicle title is the person with "rights" to the car, ie the owner, right?

Comment: In my situation, I bought two vehicles, one for me, one for my wife. Each was signed by one of us, cosigned by the other. As a result, the titles both had both of our names on it. We had to include those in the Settlement Agreement, but it was as simple as saying that I was to be assigned total ownership of both vehicles. It ended up being a bit messy because of how the divorce went down, but ultimately it turned out okay. Conferring with a lawyer is advisable.

Comment: Surely it's OP's dad's liability, and therefore taken into account when splitting assets in the divorce?

Comment: @unknownprotocol Right. And if the loan is secured, the car can also be taken by the lender if the loan isn't paid.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Gotcha, yea. I think pretty much all car loans are "secured" with the car as collateral, no? So it's really not a question of "IF the car loan was secured"